# Why did Chazal list so many manna-related miracles?

Tags: chazal, mon-manna, manna

The miracle of manna, as described in the Torah, seems to be great enough in and of itself.

Nevertheless, Chazal seemingly go out of their way to bring more and more, miracles upon miracles, about most of them there is barely a Torah source or even hint (see Yoma 74-76).

(Just the opposite, the Torah relates that people complained about the manna, and this creates a question of how could they complain about something which contains every taste? Chazal answers this, but still – it begs an explanation.)

In general, we have a rule that Hashem brings a miracle only if it is absolutely necessary.

What might be a deep motivation behind all these explanations and seemingly unnecessary, spectacular miracles?

Comment: Shir Hashirim 2:5 "He sustained me with the cream of the wheat [the manna]; because I 
was lovesick". I personally believe the deepest explanation is that this is all to do with great love. Chazal are trying to prove how much Hashem loves us "He did this for us, He did that for us..." (also showing how much they love Him). Why did Hashem make SO many stars, surely the stage is too big for the drama. Why did Hashem give us SUCH a wonderful sustenance? Love is the answer, and limitless love is expressed with limitless gifts

Answer (score 1):

I asked this question in my shul and someone gave the following answer which I liked:

Since the Torah itself goes out of its way to make the miracle greater, adding many seemingly unnecesary details (e.g. preserved quantity, changed behaviour on Shabbat), therefore Chazal "continued this line", and took every possible textual hint and explained them as further miracles.

Still, there is a deeper question remaining, of why the Torah did so. Why is the manna different from all other miracles.